# Migrated to Flink 1.10.0, now my job fails and kills my TaskManager

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I migrated from version 1.9.1 to 1.10.0 and now my program doesn't run. I'm running a simple computing topology represented in the image below.
[image: Topology]

I tried tuning the dependencies in my program and in the flink dist folder but to no avail. I moved the hadoop dependencies to `plugins/s3` but it seems that Flink's unable to find the jar. The JobManager reports:

```
2020-02-14 18:52:02,376 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-02-14 18:52:02,376 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  Starting TaskManager (Version: 1.10.0, Rev:aa4eb8f, Date:07.02.2020 @ 19:18:19 CET)
2020-02-14 18:52:02,376 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  OS current user: ubuntu
2020-02-14 18:52:02,376 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: <no hadoop dependency found>
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Private Build - 1.8/25.242-b08
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  Maximum heap size: 4432 MiBytes
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  No Hadoop Dependency available
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  JVM Options:
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -XX:+UseG1GC
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Xmx4647288761
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Xms4647288761
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1090519054
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100663296
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Dlog.file=/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/log/flink-ubuntu-taskexecutor-0-ip-10-0-1-68.log
2020-02-14 18:52:02,377 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/conf/log4j.properties
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/conf/logback.xml
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  Program Arguments:
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     --configDir
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     /home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/conf
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size=134217728b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.network.max=956301326b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.network.min=956301326b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.framework.heap.size=134217728b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,378 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.managed.size=3825205305b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.cpu.cores=8.0
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size=4513071033b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -D
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size=0b
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -  Classpath: /home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-metrics-datadog-1.10.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-metrics-statsd-1.10.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-table-blink_2.11-1.10.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-table_2.11-1.10.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar:/home/ubuntu/flink-1.10.0/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.10.0.jar::/home/ubuntu/app/conf:
2020-02-14 18:52:02,379 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using a StreamingFileSink. I get the following exception after a minute or so of now activity once I start the job:

```
2020-02-14 20:06:24
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:484)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(ExecutionGraph.java:1703)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1252)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1220)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.fail(Execution.java:955)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SingleLogicalSlot.signalPayloadRelease(SingleLogicalSlot.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SingleLogicalSlot.release(SingleLogicalSlot.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$SingleTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$MultiTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.AllocatedSlot.releasePayload(AllocatedSlot.java:149)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.releaseTaskManagerInternal(SlotPoolImpl.java:815)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.releaseTaskManager(SlotPoolImpl.java:774)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.disconnectTaskManager(JobMaster.java:429)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(JobMaster.java:1147)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatMonitorImpl.run(HeartbeatMonitorImpl.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Heartbeat of TaskManager with id 56a63a7493bc527e7af383dc008a4800 timed out.
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: This looks like a log from JobManager ;) Could You perhaps take a look at taskmanager logs ? There should be something there.

Comment: @DominikWosiński the issue is that there's not much more information than what I'm providing here. If I try  to  set the StreamingFileSink  path to a local dir, then the job runs. When I switch back to `s3(a)://...` it fails as stated above. I suspect that for some reason Flink  isn't  picking up the s3-hadoop jars. As the JobManager logs state, `No Hadoop Dependency available`.

Comment: You could try to verify this by adding the dependency to Your job and asserting that it's added to the fat-jar created.

Comment: @DominikWosiński so I created a directory in `.../plugins` without anything in it and Flink complained that it was empty. This leads me to think that it's being read. However, what I put in it is `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.10.0.jar`. If I move this file into  `.../lib` then I stop getting  the `No Hadoop Dependency available`  in  the logs and instead `Hadoop 3.1.0` gets recognized.  Adding the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.10.0` explicitly to my `build.sbt` changes nothing.

Comment: when you add something in the `lib` folder it is automatically loaded, that's why it works. Adding the library to the build/pom as a compile dependency should help you, since they added it as a provided dependency. Check the jar and if hadoop is missing there, you are not adding it the right way.

Comment: I'm currently looking into different problems with s3 plugin in 1.10. Your setup definitively looks correct. The s3 plugin should not go into lib or your build.sbt. It should be in some subfolder in plugins (as you did). The problem is that your logs are not showing much to work with. "no hadoop detected" is correct as any hadoop in the plugin is not accounted in that message. Could you please [increase log level](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/logging.html) to debug and add that?

Comment: Within the UI under Exceptions you may look at Exception History.